# Create mobile bottom navigation with Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to create a fixed [bottom navigation](http://babich.biz/perfect-bottom-navigation-for-mobile-app/) for my site when I am on a small screen.

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories). My first attempt will be to use the menubar with icons, Is that the right component for the job or is there a more suitable one?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a fixed bottom navigation on a view-port can be achieved using `MatToolbarModule` provided by Angular Material, because toolbars are built for the purpose of page headers and app navigation; and on the other hand, `MatMenuModule` is provided for the purpose of providing dropmenu-like options and not for app-level navigation.

Since Angular Material is build upon the philosophies of Material Design, so the answers to these type of design decisions lie behind the purpose and reasoning that goes into making of each component/entity.